# Are there plans to make a screensaver for Unity?

Tags: unity, screensaver

Are there plans to develop a screensaver specifically for Unity?

Since Unity uses gnome-screensaver by default currently, seems like a reasonable area for a desktop to attract much user appreciation.

(My personal interest is in a nice Pictures folder type slideshow screensaver with more settings than currently offered in gnome-screensaver - ie folder specification, and duration/delay of slide.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing I can find to reimplementing a screensaver are these blueprints:

- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-o-screensaver
- https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/security-o-compiz-screenlocking